# How to catalog search only show in homepage magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm researching magento, I have a quesion: How to catalog search only show in homepage. I finf this

```
<reference name="header">
   <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" 
          template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

How to only mapping catalogsearch to homepage.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here i assume that your homepage would be cms index page as default if yes then you can follow below xml tag to add catalog search area to display only on home page

you can add this to your `local.xml`

```
<cms_index_index>    
      <reference name="header">
            <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch"   template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
      </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

and remove it from `catalogsearch.xml`

```
 <default>
        <reference name="header">
            <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
        </reference>
 </default>
```

hope this will sure help you.